# Convergence proof of Spring Mass Damper example in Sastry's text

Tags: proof-explanation, dynamical-systems, control-theory, nonlinear-dynamics, lyapunov-functions

I have a question regarding Shankar Sastry's text "Nonlinear Systems, Analysis, Stability and Control", Page 199, Spring-mass system with damper

The equations that describe this system is,

$\dot x_1 = x_2$

$\dot x_2 = -f(x_2) - g(x_1)$,

where, $f$ and $g$ are assumed to satisfy, $\sigma f(\sigma) \geq 0, \forall \sigma \in [-\sigma_0, \sigma_0]$.

The author wishes to show that the system converges to an equilibrium state.

So he proposes a Lyapunov function,

$v(x_1, x_2) = x_2^2/2 + \int_0^{x_1} g(\sigma) d\sigma$

It is easy to show (and I agree),

$\dot v(x_1, x_2) = -x_2 f(x_2) \leq 0$ for $x_2 \in [-\sigma_0, \sigma_0]$.

**Now here's the "God move" by the author,**

**choose** $c = \min(v(-\sigma_0, 0), v(\sigma_0, 0))$,

Then the author claims:
$\dot v \leq 0$ for $x \in \Omega_c = \{(x_1, x_2): v(x_1, x_2) \leq c\}$.

As a consequence of LaSalle's principle, the trajectory enters the largest invariant set in $\Omega_c \cap \{(x_1, x_2): \dot v = 0\} = \Omega_c \cap \{x_1, 0\}$.

======================================

My question is why is it that by **choosing** $c = \min(v(-\sigma_0, 0), v(\sigma_0, 0))$, we can  conclude that $\dot v \leq 0$ for $x$ in $\Omega_c$. I have been staring at this for a while now and could not really understand how this works.

Comment: You are missing a condition on $g$, it should be similar to the condition on $f$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann the condition on $g$ would be different, since I believe one would need $$v(x_1,x_2)>0\ \forall\,x\in\Omega_c\setminus\{0\}.$$

Comment: You would need that $G(x)=\int_0^x g(u)du$ is somewhat convex with minimum at $x=0$, so at least $sign(g(x))=sign(x)$ should hold around $x=0$.

Comment: It is not really clear what is $\sigma_0$ - is it the same range for both $f$ and $g$, i.e., for $x_2$ and $x_1$? The idea of the proof is $v\le c \Rightarrow x_2 \le \sigma_0 \Rightarrow \dot{v}\le 0$. To this end, I would choose $c = v(0,\sigma_0)$.